# how does a test client work

Tags: python, testing, web, flask

maybe this question is not relevant here. let me know.

I'm trying to find out how exactly a test_client (my case, is a `Flask` `test_client`) in general works

I traced back to the `werkzeug.test.Client` [description](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/test.py#L618) (for my case, specifically)

```
"This class allows to send requests to a wrapped application."
```

But what happens under the hood? the application doesn't really run a port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask implements the WSGI application protocol. All it needs to handle a request is an `environ` dict describing the request data, and it returns a `Response` object. It doesn't care *where* the environ comes from or where the response goes, that's handled by the WSGI server protocol. The Werkzeug dev server and production servers like Gunicorn handle this part.

The Werkzeug test client simulates the server: instead of producing an `environ` in response to an HTTP request, it produces one in response to a function call. When you call `client.get`, the client builds a WSGI `environ` dict based on the arguments you pass, calls the Flask WSGI application, then returns the response to you.